# Box in hotel with which you can choose a movie to watch

Tags: word-request

Sometime at the end of the 80's, when I was still an innocent adolescent, I made my first contact with video on demand in a hotel room. There was a box under the TV set, with which you could choose from a couple of movies. The first five minutes were free, then you were charged for watching the movie (luckily, I managed to hold myself back from watching more than the free five minutes of "Amanda at Night", or howsoever that masterpiece was called).

Is there a word for this particular kind of box? My Google search was unsuccesful.

Comment: A [set-top box](http://www.hotel-online.com/News/PR2006_2nd/Jun06_HotelTVs.html)? Maybe those are newer than ones you're suggesting. That's all I could find.

Comment: A set-top box was the closest word that came to my mind. It was just because of the limitation to five or so movies that made me wonder if there is a particular word for that type of box.

Comment: Also [converters/receivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-top_box#TV_signal_sources) - apparently they existed in the 1970s.

Comment: Yes, that might be right. "Converter/receiver" appears a couple of times in a hotel context when I do a search on books/magazines from 1988.

Comment: I can't recall what it would have been called *back then*, but today this service is called "video on demand".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're being technical, then ***converter/receiver***, as noted in the comments.

For the vernacular, I recall hearing them called (in reference to that time), ***pay-per-view boxes***.